# Overriding core Drush command classes

Tags: drush

I want to add some info to the Drush status report, `drush core:status`.

Does anyone know a method to do this?

I am thinking that if there is an alter service for Drush service info, I can change the class from `drush/src/Commands/core/StatusCommands.php` to my own class that overrides it, and then overriding the [`status()` function within that class.](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/12.x/src/Commands/core/StatusCommands.php#L82), however I'm unsure of how to alter Drush service info. Can anyone provide assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commandfile should implement the Drush replace hook https://github.com/consolidation/annotated-command#replace-command-hook

Comment: Would an alternative be to use [a process hook](https://github.com/consolidation/annotated-command#process-hook) to avoid extending the core class?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I assume they were in the correct direction, Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to add to the status command. I was able to add my result to the `PropertyList` but it's not printed to the console, and I'm out of budget on this one now. Marking this as correct, but I don't actually know how it's done.

Comment: Some possible pointers: I think you'd need to ensure the new fields are printed (eg. using `--fields`) and also possibly update the command `field-labels` annotation to include the new fields - not sure what happens if you try to display a field without a label.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer. I had figured out how to add the label, but I didn't add it to --fields. I don't have client budget for this anymore, but I'm probably going to play with it a bit more on my own time to see if I can get it. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for the additional pointers.

Comment: @Jaypan – On Slack Greg Anderson said: "post-process hook is better than a replace hook (not logged in to stack exchange rn)" https://drupal.slack.com/archives/C62H9CWQM/p1695213373712919?thread_ts=1695193620.683429&cid=C62H9CWQM